# Blank Gridview Cell populates "&nbsp" into textbox

Tags: asp.net, gridview, selectedindexchanged

I've noticed that when i populate textboxes from a selected row in a gridview that if the field is blank it displays "&nbsp" in the textbox.

Here is the solution I came up with.  I check each cell before adding it to the textbox.

I get the feeling that I'm either doing something wrong to have this problem in the first place or that there is a better way to handle this.

```
protected void GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    //// Get the currently selected row using the SelectedRow property.
    GridViewRow row = GridView1.SelectedRow;

    // Load data from selected row into textboxes
    if (row.Cells[1].Text.Trim() != "&nbsp;")
    {
        txtEditCust_ID.Text = row.Cells[1].Text.Trim();
    }




}
```

Answer (score 8):

Still a minor hack, but probably better than dealing with `&nbsp;`. You can set `NullDisplayText=" "` on GridView column `<asp:BoundField>` and then use condition like for example:

```
if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(e.Row.Cells[1].Text))
{
    // do something with e.Row
}
```

In this case, there is no `&nbsp;` to begin with.

Answer (score 5):

```
row.Cells[1].Text.Trim()
```

is not working for `&nbsp;`, replace it instead:

```
row.Cells[1].Text.Replace("&nbsp;", "")
```

Answer (score 1):

This works too. Add this piece of code under your `rowDataBound` event

```
if (e.Row.Cells[1].Text.Length == 0 || e.Row.Cells[1].Text.Equals("&nbsp;") || e.Row.Cells[1].Text.Equals("") || e.Row.Cells[1].Text.Equals(string.Empty))
                {
                    e.Row.Cells[1].Text = string.Empty;
                }
```

Answer (score 1):

use

```
txtEditCust_ID.Text = Server.HtmlDecode(row.Cells[1].Text.Trim());
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `if` statement, just use:

```
txtEditCust_ID.Text = row.Cells[1].Text.Trim();
```

You are trimming it so it should remove the `&nbsp;` anyway.

Comment: `System.String.Trim()` does not remove `&nbsp;` (the text), at least not in `2.0`.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (e.Row.RowType != DataControlRowType.Header && e.Row.RowType != DataControlRowType.Footer && e.Row.RowType != DataControlRowType.Pager)
```

This removes the header, footer, and pager (if you are using) rows which took care of the `&nbsp;` for me.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check the gridview cell value whether empty or null, use this:

```
string decodeCellValue = Context.Server.HtmlDecode(e.Row.Cells[i].Text).Trim();
if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(decodeCellValue))
{
  // Cell value empty or NULL
}
else
{
  // Have some value
}
```

Comment: Please edit you answer first, check this: http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting